# Out of these two, what is the correct solution for $au_x + bu_y + cu = 0$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am reading Partial Differential Equations: An Introduction by Walter Strauss, and there's an exercise that comes with its solution at the end of the book. I also found that problem solved here: http://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/~kersale/Teach/M3414/Notes/m3414_1.pdf

The problem is that both solutions are different.

The book states that the solution is
$$u(x,y) = f(bx-ay)e^{-\frac{c}{a^2 + b^2}(ax+by)}$$

Whereas the source states that it is

$$u(x,y) = f(bx-ay)e^{-cx}$$

How come both are correct answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing: your second solution is wrong, it should be
$$u(x,y) = f(bx-ay)e^{-cx/a}\ .$$
Next: remember that $f$ is an *arbitrary* function (subject to some restrictions on differentiability).  So in this solution we can take
$$g(t)=f(t)e^{-mt}\quad\hbox{where}\quad m=\frac{bc}{a(a^2+b^2)}\ ;$$
then the solution is
$$\eqalign{u(x,y)
  &=g(bx-ay)\exp\Bigl(\frac{bc}{a(a^2+b^2)}(bx-ay)\Bigr)\exp\Bigl(-\frac{cx}a\Bigr)\cr
  &=g(bx-ay)\exp\Bigl(\frac{bc}{a(a^2+b^2)}(bx-ay)-\frac{cx}a\Bigr)\cr
  &=g(bx-ay)\exp\Bigl(-\frac{c}{a(a^2+b^2)}\bigl((a^2+b^2)x-b^2x+aby\bigr)\Bigr)\cr
  &=g(bx-ay)\exp\Bigl(-\frac{c}{a^2+b^2}\bigl(ax+by\bigr)\Bigr)\cr}$$
which is your first solution.

Comment: I did not solve this. I just copied it straight from the book, which says that is the solution. That is why I find this weird. This page http://www.math.ku.edu/~slshao/fall2013math647Homework1.pdf says on page 7 that there are different ways to write the solution though.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you solved it or copied it from a book, it's wrong.  Work out $u_x$ and $u_y$ for yourself, substitute into the LHS, simplify, and you will find it does not come out to zero.  If the book really says it's the solution, then throw the book away :)

Comment: I wish I could, it is for my class :(. I will notify the professor. I followed the characteristics method and I also get the correct answer. Thank you so much!

Comment: Maybe you should double check before telling the professor, just in case you misread the book....